# How to receive arraylist from signalR in java android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, signalr

I'm struggling to get get SignalR to map the ArrayList returned to my data model.

I have no problem mapping a single data model but not with a list.

I'm trying to something like this

```
    hub.on( "OnGetUserList", new SubscriptionHandler3<Integer, Integer, List<UserListDataModel>>() {
                @Override
                public void run(Integer arg1, Integer arg2, List<UserListDataModel> msgs) {

                }
            }, Integer.class, Integer.class, List<UserListDataModel.class>);  // Compile error
```

I have tried this as suggested in other thread but the method never gets called

```
hub.on( "OnGetUserList", new SubscriptionHandler3<Integer, Integer, UserListDataModel[]>() {
                @Override
                public void run(Integer arg1, Integer arg2, final UserListDataModel[] msgs) {
                    // never gets called
                }
            }, Integer.class, Integer.class, UserListDataModel[].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert object data into particular list or object

```
  mInstance.mHubProxy.on(SignalRConstant.CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE,
                new SubscriptionHandler2<String, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(final String msg, final Object data) {
                        if (msg != null && data != null && !data.equals("")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
                            intent.putExtra("CAPTION", msg);
                            if(msg.equals(SignalRConstant.CAPTION_LOGINPASS))
                            {
                                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(AppConstant.DATE_FORMAT).create();
                                intent.putExtra("DATA", gson.toJson(data));
                            }else{
                                intent.putExtra("DATA", data.toString());
                            }
                            sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }
                , String.class, Object.class);
```